Why do I get this "list index out of range" error?
I have a for loop, looping through a list. For some reason, when I try to access an item with the for loop variable, I have a 'list index out of range' error.
Code:
word = "APPLE"
guess = "AMPLE"

data = []
output = ""

if len(guess) != 5:
    print("Guess should be 5 letters long.")
if guess.isalpha() == False:
    print("Guess should be an English word.")
else:
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(5):
            if word[x] == guess[y]:
                if x == y:
                    data.append(guess[y] + "C" + str(y))
                else:
                    data.append(guess[y] + "W" + str(y))
            else:
                data.append(guess[y] + "I" + str(y))

    data = set(data)
    data = list(data)
    print(data) #Test             

    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(0, len(data) - i - 1):
            if str(data[j])[2] > str(data[j + 1])[2]:
                temp = data[j]
                data[j] = data[j+1]
                data[j+1] = temp
    
    print(data) #Test

    for x in range(len(data)):
        if str(data[x])[0] == str(data[x + 1])[0]:
            if str(data[x])[1] == 'C':
                data.pop(x)
            elif str(data[x])[1] == 'W':
                data.pop(x)
            else:
                data.pop(x + 1)

print(data) #Test
print(output)

Error:
if str(data[x])[0] == str(data[x + 1])[0]:
           ~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

The for loop is used as a filter in my Wordle project where it checks each item for each letter of the guess  and identifies if the output should be Green (C, meaning correct place), Yellow (W, meaning wrong place) or Gray (I, incorrect letter), then deletes the excess items.
I have tried to add or subtract quantities from the range function, and also checking how the for loops and lists interact, but to no avail.

You are removing items from your list whilst iterating over the indexes of the original length of the list.

When using a debugger, when the error occurs, what value does data[x] have?  What value did you expect it to have?  Why?

You are modifiying data as you iterate through it.  This is shortening the size of the list which results in the index error.

Hi Troy, learn about code debugging, you will be able to analyse your code step-by-step and also check what exactly causes your errors.

You probably also have a bug in your first if..if..else checks. It should probably all be a chained if..elif..else.

I don't know why this was approved from the staging ground -_- that was setting you up to fail

@tripleee The OP's problem is not that he used indices larger that the size of the initial list, as in the duplicate you suggested, but that he removes items from the list while iterating. I thought about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-while-preserving-order or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python as duplicate targets, but I think that the way the OP wants to choose which item to remove isn't really answered there, so I'll vote to reopen

This question is similar to: Index out of range. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Even if nothing was popped from the list, there would be an error on the last iteration because of the [x + 1].

There's no way you got that error. Please indent it correctly.

you are using the index (x+1) while using the range(len(data)) , which when implemented while you use the index x+1, goes beyond the range of your list.
data = ['AC0', 'AI0', 'MI1', 'PW2', 'PC2', 'PI2', 'LC3', 'LI3', 'EI4', 'EC4']

x = 0
while x < len(data) - 1:
    if data[x][0] == data[x + 1][0]:
        if data[x][1] in ['C', 'w']:
            data.pop(x)
        else:
            data.pop(x + 1)
    else:
        x += 1

print(data)

this will work well
